# How can I use full-text search with Dynamics CRM Online?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am looking for a way to use SQL server's full-text indexing for universal search in Dynamics CRM 2011 online. I know it's possible do it with the on premises version but couldn't find a way for the online version. 
And if there is no easy method, what would be a way to develop it? (maybe through a plugin?)

Comment: Minor quibble - but I assume this relates to CRM 2011 as Dynamics CRM 2010 didn't exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dynamics CRM Online doesn't expose SQL Server internals to you. It is impossible to run raw SQL.

The only methods to access your data are the CRM UI and the various SDKs/APIs (oData, REST etc)

There isn't a universal search in Dynamics CRM 2011, and I don't believe any of the third party addons will work on CRM Online due to the lack of SQL access.